# didBeginContact for three sprites works for 2 sprites, but not for the third one - Swift2

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I have a bird, multiple desks and a star. When the bird collides with one of the desks, the `didBeginContact` method works fine, but when it collides with the star, nothing happens. I will copy the code where I added some `print` statements so it is easier to see what is happening and then I will paste the print statements that it prints out.

Bird (just the initialization of the `physicsBody` part):

```
class Bird: SKSpriteNode {
    var sc: SKScene!

    init(sc: SKScene) {
        let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "hero")
        let size = texture.size()
        self.sc = sc
        super.init(texture: texture, color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: CGSizeMake(size.width/2, size.height/2))

        self.zPosition = Layer.Bird.rawValue
        self.name = "bird"

        self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: self.size.width/2)
        self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Bird
        self.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Desk
        self.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Desk | PhysicsCategory.StarSpecial | PhysicsCategory.Star

        self.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = true
        self.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
        self.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
   }

// other methods and the required init 
}
```

The star class is constructed the same way so I will just copy `physicsBody` related code:

```
    self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: self.size.width/2, center: self.position)
    self.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    self.physicsBody?.pinned = true

    self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.StarSpecial
    self.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.None
    self.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Bird
    self.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true

    self.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    self.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
    self.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
```

And the `didBeginContact` method in `GameScene`:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    print("something has collided")
    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.Bird && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.Desk {
        birdSprite.BirdDidCollideWithDesk(contact.bodyA.node as! Bird, desk: contact.bodyB.node as! Desk, scoreClass: scoreClass, scoreLabel: scoreLabel)
        print("bird and desk have collided")
    } else if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.Desk && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.Bird  {
        print("desk and bird have collided")
        birdSprite.BirdDidCollideWithDesk(contact.bodyB.node as! Bird, desk: contact.bodyA.node as! Desk, scoreClass: scoreClass, scoreLabel: scoreLabel)
    }

    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.Bird && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.StarSpecial {
        print("collided into star1")
        starSpecial.removeStar(contact.bodyB.node as! Star)
    } else if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.StarSpecial && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.Bird {
        print("collided into star2")
        starSpecial.removeStar(contact.bodyB.node as! Star)
    }
}
```

If I run it, I get the following messages:

1. If the bird collides with a desk: `"something has collided"`, `"desk and bird have collided"`
2. If the bird collides with the star: `"something has collided"`

Neither of second two conditions is met, so the message `"collided into star1"` or `"collided into star2"` is not printed out.

Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: What is the result of you print the category: print("Body A"  + String(contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask))

Comment: I have no idea how, but for some reason it works fine now. I didn't change a single thing so I don't know what was wrong, maybe just some XCode bug. But I actually have a different problem now.. I have clouds floating in the air and shouldn't be able to collide with the bird. The bird collision bit mask is set to collide just with the desk, and clouds have collision bit mask set to 0. But they do collide and use the `didBeginContact` method. Do you have any idea why this could be happening? Maybe something wrong with my Xcode?